# Is it possible to delete all the previous message by bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, telegram, telegram-bot

Currently bot has option to show welcome messages for the new `new_chat_members` which shows for each member. There are plenty of welcome messages staying in group due to the high volume of new members. iIt is bit irritating for the current users showing multiple number of welcome messages.

```
const welcomeMessage = (ctx) => {
  const { new_chat_members } = ctx.message;
  const newMembers = new_chat_members.filter( member => member.is_bot === false)
  var membersName = newMembers.map( usr =>{ 
    let fullname = [usr.first_name,usr.last_name].join(" ");
    return fullname;
  });
  ctx.replyWithMarkdown(`Welcom ${membersName.join(', ')}`);
}
bot.on('new_chat_members', welcomeMessage);
```

Is there any option to delete all the previous welcome messages ?

The telegram bot use in https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf

Answer (score 4):

your bot doesn't have on-demand access to the messages in the group(it can only get the messages as updates.) if you have saved the message_ids per each welcome message, so you can delete the messages having (chatID,messageID) pairs.
there is another way which is viable: use telegram core api and
0xafa92846: functions.messages.GetHistoryRequest api to get messages in the group. then you can find welcome messages by parsing them and then you can delete them.